# Best IDE for 32-bit microcontroller on Linux

Tags: microcontroller, atmel, ide

I'm choosing a 32-bit microcontroller to implement a Kalman filter.

I am very attracted to the Atmel Studio 6 IDE. However, it only appears to run on Windows.

Could anyone suggest a good Linux IDE?

Otherwise, I think I'll go with Atmel Studio 6 IDE in a virtual machine.

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Geany is small, fast and has a good feature set. I have used it for embedded development on Linux and found it to be quite useful.

PS: Here is the link to their site: http://www.geany.org/. Good though it is, I'd still recommend you to go ahead with Atmel Studio because IMO it is the best free IDE for embedded ever made.

Comment: Yes, I think I'm going to go with Atmel Studio... A Windows VM is a minor inconvenience I guess.

Comment: I don't know whether the 32bit Atmels are supported, but at least for the 8bit AVRs I prefer Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

I run Atmel Studio 6 in a VM, and it works fine. It will probably be the simplest method for you.

Otherwise I like to use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) in Linux, it is also available in Windows too, and it has a lot more features than most other Linux IDE's. Or as @elf said, [Geany](http://www.geany.org) for more basic projects.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of Code::Blocks, but I use my own makefiles as the back-end rather than their build system.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of 32-bit? If it's ARM, Rowley Crossworks is an IDE many people seem to like and it has native Linux support. http://www.rowley.co.uk/ It's not free though.